# Angular protractor with travis ci can not find webdriver-manager

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, protractor

I am using angular js and protractor and i am trying to use travis ci to run my tests but i get this error:

```
The command "node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update" failed and exited with 127 during.

/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager: No such file or directory
```

This is my travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
before_script:
  - "npm install -g protractor"
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - 'webdriver-manager update'
  - 'webdriver-manager start 2>&1 &'
```

What am i missing?

Comment: you can try to download selenium standalone (.jar file) from official site and try to do it like this: java -jar filename.jar - it will start selenium server